# An integral with $e^{1+e^x}$ I had trouble working through

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I had an analysis test earlier this morning and came across this integral, which I couldn't figure out. Parts of it are easy, but after integrating $y$ you're left integrating $xe^{1+e^x}$ which had me stumped.

$\displaystyle\int^1_0 \int^{1 + e^x}_x xe^y dy dx$

What did I miss? I couldn't think of any substitutions or any change of variables that would help me here.

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*e%5Ey+on+x%3D0..1%2C+y%3Dx..e%5E%281%2Bx%29) gives me the numerical solution, but doesn't provide the step-by-step, otherwise I'd walk through that.

Comment: I suspect that the right way to do this is to reverse the order of integration (which requires a geometric analysis of your region of integration). But the function you get by integrating directly is rather interesting, since it's related to the _generating function_ of the Bell numbers $\{B_n\}$: $$e^{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{B_n}{n!}x^n.$$ (In shorter words: you're probably not supposed to do it this way, but this way does have some interesting features!)

Comment: Reversing the order dosnt lead to any easy answers.

Comment: Given the rest of the test, and the class I would suspect that there is an easy way to solve this one.

Comment: I'm going to take a swing at the reversal of order. I can't see any other 'easy' way that'd show up on an exam.

Comment: In your Wolfram calculation, the upper limit on $x$ is $e^{1+x},$ not the same as in the post which is $1+e^x$. Which is it?

Comment: While I'd like to see that point clarified as well, it doesn't seem to make much difference: one ends up in either case with the integral $\int_0^1 x e^{e^x}\,dx$ as the obstruction to finding a result. So far, I've seen nothing that makes that tractable (including reversal of order, to my chagrin). @coffeemath

Comment: After integration by parts, the problem boils down to $\int Ei(e^x)dx$ which is the exponential integral...so a series expansion could do it. Though finding a closed form could be difficult

Comment: @TylerHG: Are you certain? I was seeing similar results as well, but I noticed that I was omitting the $x$ that's in the integrand to start with. (After some prodding I was able to get a closed from from Mathematica; it includes $Ei$, but also $\gamma$ and a hypergeometric $_3F_3$ function.)

Comment: Yea pretty sure, as $\int \exp(e^x)dx=Ei(e^x)+C$ so integration by parts will get us to the integral of $Ei$ no?

Comment: The post is correct, the link to the wolfram alpha solution is incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps the upper bound on the inner integral was meant to be $x+e^x$ instead of $1+e^x$.

Comment: So choose $u=x$ and $dv=\exp(e^x)dx$ @Semiclassical

Comment: At this poit I have to think that whoever wrote the problem didn't realize how hard it was, or a typo crept in somehow: this just doesn't have an elementary result...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something myself...but,                   $$\int x\exp(e^x)dx=xEi(e^x)-\int Ei(e^x)dx$$  Just by one application of integration by parts. Because: $$\int \exp(e^x)dx=Ei(e^x)+C$$

Comment: I see it now, thanks for clearing up the confusion. @tylerhg

Answer (score 1):

Since my attempts to find a 'nice' solution have met with failure, let me at least follow the thought I presented in the comments. Recalling that $$e^{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{B_n}{n!}x^n$$ where $B_n$ are the Bell numbers, we have the integral

$$\int_0^1 x\,e^{e^x-1} dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}\int_0^1 x^{n+1} dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{(n+2)\,n!}\approx 1.49$$
But that's as far as one can go, as this expression appears not to have any useful closed forms (certainly nothing elementary).